# What is the parts of speech of these words?

Tags: past-participles, parsing

> On 20 July 1969, Apollo 11 was  first manned mission to land on the Moon.There were also   landings.

I want to know the parts of speech of these bold words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"The"** is a *determiner* - the *definite article*. It is used here because only one thing can be "first" among others, so it is *the first* manned moon landing of all the subsequent manned moon landings.

**"Numerous"** and **"unmanned"** are both *adjectives* modifying the noun "landing". Multiple adjectives can be strung together before a noun. The moon landings referred to were all *numerous* (meaning there were many of them) and *unmanned* (no humans aboard).

Comment: But what is the exact parts of speech of "The "?

Comment: @HasibRahman What do you mean "part"?

Comment: I know that here "the" word is an article. But I want to know that the word "the" is in which parts of speech.

Comment: _The_ is always the definite article.

Comment: @HasibRahman Again, what do you mean by "parts of speech"? It is the *determiner*, which I've stated. I don't know what else you could mean by "parts of speech". It's the middle part?

Answer (score 0):

On 20 July 1969, Apollo 11 was  first manned mission to land on the Moon.There were also   landings.

The parts of speech are:

*The* - determinative

*Numerous* - adjective

*Unmanned* - adjective

The adjective "numerous" modifies the nominal "unmanned landings".